# Direct Product of Torsion Subgroups

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification

So I came up with this theorem while studying, and concocted a small proof, and I was wondering if someone could verify it, as I am very new to torsion groups/elements. I am open to all criticism. Thanks!

Note: $T(G)$ denotes the torsion subgroup of $G$. That is,

$$T(G) = \{g\in G\ |\ |g|<\infty\}.$$

Theorem:

Let $A$ and $B$ be abelian groups. Then:
$$T(A\times B) = T(A)\times T(B).$$
Proof:

Suppose that $(a,b)\in T(A\times B)$. Then, $|(a,b)| =n$ for some positive integer $n$. So:
        \begin{align}
  \notag (a,b)^n &= (1_A,1_B)\\
  \notag (a^n,b^n) &= (1_A,1_B)
  \end{align}
    Thus $a^n=1_A$ and $b^n=1_B$. Therefore, $a\in T(A)$, $b\in T(B)$, and we must have $(a,b)\in T(A)\times T(B)$, and thus $T(A\times B)\subseteq T(A)\times T(B)$. Now, suppose that $(a,b)\in T(A)\times T(B)$. Then, both $a$ and $b$ have finite order. Let $\ell=|a|\cdot |b|$. Then:
$$(a,b)^{\ell} = (a^{\ell},b^{\ell}) = (1_A,1_B).$$
Thus $(a,b)$ has finite order and we must have $(a,b)\in T(A\times B)$. So $T(A)\times T(B)\subseteq T(A\times B)$, and with the above inclusion, we must also have:
$$T(A\times B) = T(A)\times T(B).$$

Comment: The proof is absolutely fine.

Comment: @whosleon Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This proof is perfectly correct, but I have one remark. (This is definitely pedantry, but I think for a proof of this kind, it's not something you should overlook.) You take $\ell=\vert a\vert \vert b\vert $, and immediately note that $a^\ell=1=b^\ell$. If you want to make this exceedingly clear, you might write $a^\ell=(a^{\vert a\vert})^{\vert b\vert}=1^{\vert b\vert}=1$, etc.. You are using a property of abelian groups (which itself has to be proved), namely that $(a^n)^m=a^{nm}$, and at this level, it's worth making this clear.

Comment: Excellent. That is actually very constructive. I am currently working through Dummit & Foote, and I have actually already proven that statement as an exercise, but I am logging all of my proofs and hyper-linking what facts the proofs depend on. Thanks!

Comment: Dear @chs21259, You're welcome!